# Youtube API v3 from a PhoneGap app on Android

Tags: android, cordova, youtube, youtube-api, phonegap-build

I'm writing an Android PhoneGap app which uses the Youtube API v3. This means that the Android app opens a web view and runs a web app (js/html) that accesses the API via XHRs.

I've tried using a browser key but the referrer is missing from the XHRs. I've also tried creating an Android key, but it was rejected by the YT server.

Any ideas on how to get this to work (other than making my key open to ALL referers)?

If anyone knows how the API knows which Android app is sending a request when using an Android key, I might be able to replicate that in the web view.

thanks.